# How to pass string ( {{$variable->variable}} into ajax onclick function

Tags: ajax, laravel

html code ( string value : "test abc") :

```
<button id = 'ajaxlink' onClick='showfield(/"+"{{$collection_summary->pbt}}"+/")'>Click me</button>
```

JS :

```
function showfield(a) {alert(a);}
```

Error Message : Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

There is no issue if i pass the integer value, suspected the error with string pass into the onclick function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do `"{{$collection_summary->pbt}}"` like this:

```
<button id='ajaxlink' onClick='showfield("{{$collection_summary->pbt}}")'>Click me</button>
```